# How to create jooq custom record?

Tags: java, sql, jooq

How can I create a custom jOOQ Record from existing two others, i.e. merge properties from two existing Record Objects.

For example:

```
CustomerRecord(id, name, surname), 
ProductRecord(id, customer_id, description)
```

```sql
SELECT * FROM Customer JOIN Product ON Customer.id = Product.customer_id;
```

After such a query I'll get RecordImpl object and I want to have custom one with access to field properties from both tables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several options to achieve what you're looking for.

#### Use views

One of them would be to simply create a view:

```sql
-- Potentially disambiguate the ID (and other) columns
CREATE VIEW CustomerAndProducts AS
SELECT * FROM Customer JOIN Product ON Customer.id = Product.customer_id;
```

The code generator would then pick up that view and generate a `CustomerAndProductsRecord` for you

#### Use your own `CustomRecord`

You can create your own `TableRecord` subtype by extending [`org.jooq.impl.CustomRecord`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/CustomRecord.html) as is documented here:
https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/queryparts/custom-queryparts

They work almost like ordinary `TableRecord` types and can have your own set of getters / setters

#### Use any class you like

You don't have to use records. jOOQ can fetch your results into any kind of class (which may happen to be records, see above) using the following code:

```java
List<MyClass> list =
DSL.using(configuration)
   .select()
   .from(CUSTOMER)
   .join(PRODUCT)
   .on(CUSTOMER.ID.eq(PRODUCT.CUSTOMER_ID))
   .fetchInto(MyClass.class);
```

In the above example, the [`DefaultRecordMapper`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DefaultRecordMapper.html) is applied to map between jOOQ's records and your class. [See its Javadoc for details](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DefaultRecordMapper.html).